# R cannot be resolved to a variable why?

Tags: eclipse, android-resources

I have this

```
public GamePanel(Context context, Game game,int ScreenWidth,int Screenheigt) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.game = game;
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
    background = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_fon), ScreenWidth, this);
    BM = new Barriermanager(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barier), this);
    BM.setScreen(ScreenWidth, Screenheigt);
    ship = new Ship(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player), 100, 0, ScreenWidth, Screenheigt);
    coin = new Bonus(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bonus), -200,-200);
    ArrayList<Bitmap> animation = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boom1));
    animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boom2));
    animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boom3));
    animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.boom4));
    ship.setBoomAnimation(animation);
```

please help! The "R" cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Can you provide more code, like where the add method is called, as well as the exception generated and stack trace provided?

Comment: public GamePanel(Context context, Game game,int ScreenWidth,int Screenheigt) {
  super(context);
  getHolder().addCallback(this);
  this.game = game;
  thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
  background = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_fon), ScreenWidth, this);
  BM = new Barriermanager(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.barier), this);

Comment: BM.setScreen(ScreenWidth, Screenheigt);
  ship = new Ship(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player), 100, 0, ScreenWidth, Screenheigt);
  coin = new Bonus(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bonus), -200,-200);
  ArrayList<Bitmap> animation = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

Comment: It would be super-helpful if you edited your original post with the code properly formatted...

Comment: 'R' is a class in the 'android' package. You seem to have an error in your project setup.